# How to update the updated service value in all the components using angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-directives

we have two components shared same service, we change the service value in one component that value i need to update other component also.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ConfigurationService} from './first.servvice';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers : [ConfigurationService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title : boolean;
  constructor(private configurationService:ConfigurationService){
    this.title = this.configurationService.toggle;
  }


}



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root1',
  templateUrl: './app.component1.html',
   providers : [ConfigurationService]
})
export class AppComponent1 {
  title : boolean;
  constructor(private configurationService:ConfigurationService){
      this.title = this.configurationService.toggle;
  }
  change(){
    this.configurationService.toggle = ! this.configurationService.toggle;
    this.title = this.configurationService.toggle;
  }
}
```

Service .ts

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {
 toggle :boolean = false;
}
```

i need to update the service value when we update the service value in other components also.

Code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/LtrflSk7bICMC2xmacS5?p=preview

Comment: Use [events](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the rxjs `Subject`. In your service, do the following change:

```
import {Subject} from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {
    toggle: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
}
```

.. and wherever you are using this value from service, subscribe to the `toggle`:

```
this.configurationService.toggle.subscribe(value => this.title = value);
```

.. when you want to change/update it, then you can do the following:

```
this.configurationService.toggle.next(!this.configurationService.toggle);
```

Link to you [**updated plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/MorafH0xYWm8nACXAufQ?p=preview).

Comment: If i am try to display the {{title}} in both component im getting empty . After i called "change() method title value only updated in one component not for two

Comment: what i feel is "this.configurationService.toggle.subscribe(value => this.title = value);" it is not working properly